# Selecting ONLY Duplicates from a joined tables query

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by, duplicates, large-data

I have the following query that I'm trying to join two tables matching their ID so I can get the duplicated values in "c.code". I've tried a lot of queries but nothing works. I have a 500k rows in my database and with this query I only get 5k back, which is not right. Im positive it's at least 200K. I also tried to use Excel but it's too much for it to handle.
Any ideas?
Thanks in advance, everyone.

```
SELECT c.code, c.name as SCT_Name, t.name as SYNONYM_Name, count(c.code)
FROM database.Terms as t
  join database.dbo.Concepts as c on c.ConceptId = t.ConceptId
  where t.TermTypeCode = 'SYNONYM' and t.ConceptTypeCode = 'NAME_Code' and c.retired = '0'
   Group by c.code, c.name, t.name
   HAVING COUNT(c.code) > = 1

Order by c.code
```

Comment: Is `code` a nullable column? What kinds of count values are you getting from that query. Remember that `group by` will collapse the original rows into single rows so with a lot of duplicates 5k could be correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
with data as (
    select c.code, c.name as SCT_Name, t.name as SYNONYM_Name
    from database.Terms as t inner join database.dbo.Concepts as c
        on c.ConceptId = t.ConceptId
    where
            t.TermTypeCode = 'SYNONYM'
        and t.ConceptTypeCode = 'NAME_Code'
        and c.retired = '0'
)
select *
    --, (select count(*) from data as d2 where d2.code = data.code) as code_count
    --, count(*) over (partition by code) as code_count
from data
where code in (select code from data group by code having count(*) > 1)
order by code
```

Comment: Thank you so much Shawnt00. This was exactly what I needed! Thank you! Thank you everyone who helped me.

Answer (score 0):

If you want just duplicates of c.code, your Group By is wrong (and so is your Having clause). Try this:

```
SELECT c.code
FROM database.Terms as t
  join database.dbo.Concepts as c on c.ConceptId = t.ConceptId
  where t.TermTypeCode = 'SYNONYM' and t.ConceptTypeCode = 'NAME_Code' and c.retired = '0'
   Group by c.code
   HAVING COUNT(c.code) > 1
```

This will return all rows where you have more than one c.code value.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Randy, but I got 0 in return.

Comment: @Beavis855 - Then you don't have any duplicates, given your Where clause.

Comment: We do have duplicates. c.code is a numeric value that repeats in that column but with different alphabetic values in the other two columns. Does it make sense? i.e c.code 1 text One

Comment: I think your Where clause is filtering all your duplicates. Try removing it.

Comment: It's not. That part is correct. I have those 3 columns with different data in it so I was filtering for the ones I actually want to read and I do have duplicates in c.code with different values in c.name and t.name.

Comment: Hi, just letting you know that I got what I was looking for and wanted to thank you again for helping me today. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need to use INTERSECT instead of JOIN. Basically you perform the select on the first table then intersect with the second table. The result is the duplicate rows.

Only select the id column, though, otherwise the intersect won't work as expected.

Comment: Thank you Philippe, but it didn't work. "Intersect" turns my second table invalid.

Comment: Is c.retired really a char column? Because c.retired = '0' seems odd. And what do you mean by turns invalid?

Comment: Everything up until "Group by" is correct. We have that Retired part to identify what code is valid (0) and which one is not valid anymore (1). I got the Group by part and Having from the forum here. However it doesnt work when I have the join in my query. Once I re-wrote it with Intersect, my Concepts as c turns "red". Makes sense?

Comment: But is the retired a char or an int column? I think 2-3 lines of sample data would be helpful.

Comment: c.code                c.name                          t.name
10001005 Bacteria              Bacteria 1
10001005 Bacteria             Bacteria 2
10001005 Bacteria            Bacteria 3
10001005 Bacteria            Bacteria 4
10001005 Bacteria            Bacteria 5
10002003 Feline                 Feline0
10002003 Feline                Feline1
10002003 Feline                 Feline2

That's what I get when I run my regular query up to the Group by part. I'm interested in getting the repeats to check if the values in c.name and t.name actually are right or not, then I'll need to edit.

Comment: Hi, just letting you know that I got what I was looking for and wanted to thank you again for helping me today. Thanks!